# php start php script and continue

Tags: php, system, exec, continue, passthru

At the moment I have a line of code like this:

```
system("/usr/bin/php myphpscript.php --param=".val);
```

Is there a way to make php *not* wait for the script to finish - and just move on instead?

It's a loop moving email, and the myphpscript.php is parsing the mails. And I **don't** wan't to wait for myphpscript.php to finish each time - just start it and move on!

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

Found the answer here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506

```
passthru("/usr/bin/php myphpscript.php --param=".val." >> /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Exp:

> > /dev/null

I needed to write to something else that STDOUT, else PHP will hang untill script finish. So I write to /dev/null instead.

```
2>&1
```

Redirecting errors to STDOUT

```
&
```

"Run in background" as mentioned in this thread.

Have a good day!

- jack
- jack

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
exec("/usr/bin/php myphpscript.php --param=".val . '&');
```

Comment: This solution+nohup gives me "nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout" + my subscript output. Without nohup, just give me subscript output. (In my terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Throwing the background command to the end should le the script continue:

system("/usr/bin/php myphpscript.php --param=".val . "&");

I'd also add nohup just to be safe, since I think this sub-process might get killed when the parent php script finishes:

system("nohup /usr/bin/php myphpscript.php --param=".val . "&");

Comment: I've added your changes, but if I run the script through a terminal - the script is still waiting for myphpscript.php to be done. And then my IMAP connection will time out. Is there a way to make the main script move on after starting the subscript?